# Avoiding Data Concurrency in asp.net MC4 by updating view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, concurrency

I currently have a delete button displaying to delete an object only if certain requirements are met.

Example: User A opens edit page and requirements are met so delete button is set to display. User A has page open while User B performs a change on the object that User A is displaying. This now voids the initial requirements and the object is no longer able to be deleted. The delete button should not be visible/enabled to the user.

What I currently do is just do a check in the called method to make sure the requirements are still met before proceeding with the delete. If it fails then disregard the delete and display proper message to user.

This got me wondering if there was anyway in asp.net mvc to use something like the observer pattern and register all controller object instances who are currently on this page to be notified if a certain requirement has changed. Then using ajax, update that specific object to either hide the button or display a message/modal window notifying the user that a change has been made by another user and the object can no longer be deleted?

Comment: Check out SignalR http://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: You have to implement simple javascript long polling by yourself (http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) or use SignalR (it will be useful by the reason of  integration with Asp.NET)